# broadband not accessible

Tags: 13.04, networking, internet, windows-8

I've installed ubuntu 13.04 along side windows 8, both on different partition.
And I've 512kbps broadband connection of local operator with username & password enabled.
I can smoothly connect to internet via windows 8.

But in ubuntu, it's like a headache.
I've tried a lot but it's not either connecting or giving internet access.

Can anybody help me out with this?? I really want to get rid out of this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Give some more information like, are you using a wireless broadband or a wired one? Does the icon on `top panel` shows connected.

Comment: @SauravKumar: I'm using **wired broadband** single user connection. And about icon only a single time it was connected with no internet access. Rest the time its **not connected** at all.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you, since it was so long so written as an answer. Give it a try and reply what happens..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it will work or not but you can give it a try. It is safe so no need to worry.

Follow these steps.

- First take a backup of `/etc/network/interfaces`

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.back
  ```
- Open `/etc/network/interfaces` by `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` and replace the contents with this:

  ```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
  ```
- Save and close `gedit`and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo ifup eth0
  ```

  or/and

  ```
  sudo dhclient eth0
  ```
- Try to connect again, also try to restart you system once.
- If it doesn't work then I am sorry! this would not be your solution. Replace your new `/etc/network/interfaces` file with original one: `/etc/network/interfaces.back`:

  ```
  sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces.back /etc/network/interfaces
  ```

  and run:

  ```
  sudo dhclient eth0
  ```

Reply what happens.

Comment: This isn't work in my case! Thanx anyway!! :)